# Specify a border which has two different colors in PURE CSS

Tags: html, css, border

Can I specify a border like 1px solid color1/color2. for the situation if I have to put a border like the image attached. I know I can put this border as an image, but I am looking if this can be be done in pure css.[image: I want border like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also achieve the effect of multiple borders on an element with the pseude elements `:before` and `:after`.
See this page for examples http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/demo/borders.html

Here is ja demo using this technice (only top border as you described it): http://jsfiddle.net/m7g6L/

```
div {
    border-top: 3px solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Enclose the element within a div, then use the div to achieve the desired effect by eliminating the margin and border from the div, like this:

```
<div style="border-top: solid red 2px; margin: none; padding: 0px;">
<p style="margin-top: 0px; border-top: solid blue 2px;">This is a paragraph.Blah Blah 
Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

It worked when I tried it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `outline:`.

Fair warning: it might mess the focus with some elements.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MGuMM/)**

Comment: if I have to say just border-top or border-bottom, what will happen to outline

Answer (score 1):

you could use multiple elements and play with the padding and backgrounds:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJFx4/

not exactly semantic but it works -- you could use pseudo elements to achieve the same effect

Comment: i dont want to create an unnecessary div and give white background to create an illusion,
http://jsfiddle.net/SJFx4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, CSS does not support multiple borders as far as I know.

Nonetheless, you can visually acheive the desired effect by combining an ordinary border with an outline:

```
#myElement    {
    border:  solid 2px blue;
    outline: solid 2px red;
}
```

If you need the outer "border" to appear only on one side, for example `top`, then the simplest solution is to use an enclosing div element:

```
div .borderHelper    {
    border-top:  solid 2px red;
    margin:      none;
    padding:     0;
}

#myElement    {
    border-top:  solid 2px blue;
}
```

Comment: Again but I just need this for border-top or border-bottom of elements

Comment: is there really something called outline-top and outline-bottom, see Truth's comment

Comment: Dear, that's true, there is only `outline`... I am sorry, I really thought that thoses properties existed. I have learned something thanks to you.